# Find the gradient and stated value for x?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$f(x)=x^{\frac{1}{3}}$ where $x=27$
i did it in this way
=$3\sqrt{27}$ 
=3

but the answer is ${\frac{1}{27}}$ 
this chapter name is (differentiationg rational power
$x^{\frac{p}{q}}$)
Can you please help me to solve this question? 
thanks in advance

Comment: First find $f'(x)$: $f'(x)={1\over3}x^{{1\over3}-1}={1\over3} x^{-2/3}={{1\over 3 x^{2/3}}}$.  Now evaluate $f'(27)$.

Comment: sorry @DavidMitra i still don't get it! Can you plz explain more?

Comment: Explain more *what*? You should be taking the derivative at some point (first, as it turns out). You never took the derivative. So that's a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First find $f'(x)$. This is important, find the general form of the derivative first:

Using the power rule
$$
{d\over dx} x^a=ax^{a-1},
$$ 
we have,

$$f'(x)=  {d\over dx}x^{1/3}={\textstyle{1\over3}}x^{{1\over3}-1}={\textstyle{1\over3}} x^{-2/3}={{1\over 3 x^{2/3}}}.$$

So, whatever $x$ is (as long as it isn't zero),
$$
f'(x)={{1\over 3 x^{2/3}}}.
$$
Now you know the rule for the function $f'(x)$, and you can evaluate $f'(27)$.

Can you take it from here? (Note $27^{2/3}=(27^{1/3})^2$. )

Comment: the problem is there is no x in 27

Comment: @SbSangpi The derivative of $f$ is a function.  You could be asked for $f'(1)$ or $f'(9)$, or $f'(27)$.  That is why you find a formula for $f'(x)$.  Once you have that, you can use it to find $f'(x)$ for $x=27$ or for $x$ equal to whatever.

Comment: $=27^{\frac{2}{3}}$

Comment: Good answer. The first comment definitely [made me wonder...](http://memegenerator.net/instance/17713910)

Comment: but my answer is 1/27 not $=27^{\frac{2}{3}}$

Comment: @SbSangpi $f'(x)={1\over 3x^{2/3}}$; so $f'(27)={1\over 3\cdot 27^{2/3}}={1\over 3\cdot 9}={1\over27}$. This is just evaluating a function ($f'$ here) at a point ($x=27$).

Comment: hehe..thx! understood now!